# Android in-app language switcher works with emulator and local device, but not when published in Google Play (signed bundle)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, localization, google-play-developer-api

I have an in-app language switcher in a Kotlin app (two buttons, one button for English, one button for Romanian).

It does not work on devices with Android 12 (API level 32) and lower. On the newer ones, it works perfectly.

I'm following the [official guide here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages#api-implementation). I have a class LocaleHelper, that has this method:

```
fun setLanguage(language: String) {
    App.preferences.edit().putString(App.LANGUAGE_SELECTION, language).apply()
    val tag = "$language-RO"
    val appLocale: LocaleListCompat = LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags(tag)
    AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(appLocale)
}
```

which I'm calling when a language button is clicked:

```
 when (item?.itemId) {
        R.id.romanian_button -> {
            LocaleHelper().setLanguage("ro")
        }
        R.id.english_button_button -> {
            LocaleHelper().setLanguage("en")
        }
    }
```

The Romanian language IS available on users devices, because in the MainActivity.kt, I'm already downloading the additional language (Romanian) according to the [official Google code sample from github](https://github.com/android/app-bundle-samples/blob/main/DynamicFeatures/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/samples/dynamicfeatures/MainActivity.kt#L202).

Also, in AndroidManifest.xml I've put this, according to [the official guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages#android12-impl) for older devices:

```
<application>
...
<service
    android:name="androidx.appcompat.app.AppLocalesMetadataHolderService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false">
        <meta-data
        android:name="autoStoreLocales"
        android:value="true" />
</service>
...
</application>
```

The problem is that on devices with Android 12 (API level 32) and lower, this does nothing. When I tap the flags, nothing happens, the language remains English, even if the activity is recreating itself. On newer devices, this code works. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem. Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: No, unfortunately I haven't found a solution. I ended up removing English from my app, leaving it only with the local language (Romanian), for better compatibility with older devices.